# Selecting rows in a CSV file based on column value that contains an embedded comma

Tags: command-line, awk, csv

I have a CSV file with 4 columns: `Date`, `User`, `Email` and `Comment`

How would I filter the rows that have `too much, later` in the `Comment` column and then read it into a new file called `input1.csv`?

Below is what I tried, but `input1.csv` came out blank:

```
awk -F , '$4 == "too much, later" { print }' input.csv > input1.csv
```

Here is the sample input:

```
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,too much,later
```

Comment: can you provide the sample file contents.. you should redirect the output using greater than symbol ( > input1.csv )

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Data  User Email Comment
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com too much, later
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com It's too expensive 
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com Other Reason
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com It's too expensive 
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com Other Reason
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com I don't like

Comment: @CharlesMarshall edit your question and add the example input to it. Please format it according to site format. I.e. Inserting 4 spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: @CharlesMarshall I do not see any comma in your example, why are you using `-F ,` in your code?

Comment: Do add the CSV formatted _text_ of the sample input. It makes it so much easier to test. http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: @CharlesMarshall Export the data to a CSV file, then copy and paste the contents of the sample into the text of the question. From the terminal, yes, for example.

Comment: @CharlesMarshall Add it to the _question_. Click `edit` under the question itself. In the edit interface, select the data and format it as code by selecting `{}` from the edit menu on the web page.

Comment: Exporting inte CSV from a spreadsheet program _usually_ adds the necessary quotes around the data that needs it. The fourth column is not quoted, and the header line contains spaces in the names of each header. It is not properly formatted CSV.

Comment: @Kusalananda this is copied straight from my TextEdit application

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `awk`, but it's awkward. :) It's much better to do it with a real CSV parser, such as [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
csvgrep -c Comment -m 'too much, later' file.csv
```

Comment: This is what I got when I ran that command: usage: csvgrep [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
               [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z FIELD_SIZE_LIMIT] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H]
               [-v] [-l] [--zero] [-n] [-c COLUMNS] [-m PATTERN] [-r REGEX]
               [-f MATCHFILE] [-i]
               [FILE]
csvgrep: error: unrecognized arguments: input.csv

Comment: Works fine here with `csvgrep` 1.0.2. _shrug_

Comment: Do you have an email that I can send the file to?  You could try running it on your end and see if it works @Satu Katsura

Comment: Right: it doesn't work with the sample input you have now shown, because the last field in your sample is not properly quoted.  It works with proper CSV files though. _shrug_

Answer (score 2):

I see a simple problem: the string `too much, later` contains a `,` (comma) and your field separator is also `,`, so the $4 parameter will be `too much` and $5 will be `later`.

You could change you code to:

```
awk -F , '$4 == "too much" && $5 == "later " { print }' input.csv > input1.csv
```

Note that this solution will work only if last field is exactly `too much,later` (note the ending space in the string).

A regex based solution is more robust:

```
awk -F , '/,\s*too\s+much,\s*later\s*/{ print }' input.csv > input1.csv
```

In this solution, you can have any amount of space character in the string.

Comment: I tried the your first suggestion and input1.csv came out blank.  Your 2nd option produced this error: awk: non-terminated string  { print }... at source line 1
 context is
  >>>  <<<
awk: giving up
 source line number 2

Comment: Ops, I fixed the second example. I pasted a `"` too much

Comment: As @kamaraj commented, an example of you input will be useful. Details can change according to it. You have to adapt our examples to your real input files.

Comment: Data  User Email Comment
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com too much, later
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com It's too expensive 
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com Other Reason
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com It's too expensive 
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com Other Reason
1/22/17 0:00 aaaa xxxxxx@xxxxx.com I don't like 
1/22/17 0:00 Brenda xxxxxx@xxxxx.com Other Reason

Comment: I tried the revision @andcoz and input1.csv came out blank again.

Comment: @andcoz awk's default action for any condition is to print the record so you could just write `awk -F '/too much, later$/' input.csv > input1.csv`

Comment: @CharlesMarshall I adapted the code to your example.

Comment: @ValentinB. Yes, I know but I prefer my version for readability ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming properly formatted CSV:

```
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,"too much, later"
```

This works, using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvgrep -c Comment -m 'too much, later' data.csv
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,"too much, later"

$ csvgrep -c 4 -m 'too much, later' data.csv
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,"too much, later"
```

Alternatively, using `sed` (since we know it's in the last column):

```
$ sed -n -e '1p' -e '/too much, later"$/p' data.csv
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,"too much, later"
```

With the data as shown in the question:

```
$ sed -n -e '1p' -e '/too much,later$/p' data.csv
Date,User,Email,Comment
11/22/16,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,too much,later
```

Comment: I appreciate the help @Kusalananda, but now it is just returning the headers in the new file.  Can I send it to your email and you can run on from your command line?

Comment: @CharlesMarshall I've update the answer. Your CSV is severely broken (at least the way it's shown in the question). I will not give out my email on this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," 'NF>4 { 
    b=$0; $1=$2=$3=""
    if (match($0,/too much, ?later/)) 
        print b
}' OFS="," input.csv > input1.csv
```