# Selecting rows in a CSV file based on column value that contains an embedded comma

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, awk, csv

I have a CSV file (CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (.csv)) with 5 columns: customer data, customer first name, customer email, cancel reason, cancel reason comments

How would I filter the rows that have "Wanted item later, choose not to get it later" in the cancel reason column and then read it into a new file called input1.csv?

Below is what I tried, but input1.csv came out blank:

```
awk -F , '$4 == "Wanted item later, choose not to get it later" { print }' input.csv > input1.csv
```

Here is a sample input from input.csv file:

```
cancellation date,customer first name,customer email,cancel reason,cancel reason comments
1/22/17,aaaa,xxxxx@xxxxx.com,"Wanted item later, choose not to get it later", test
```

Comment: `awk` knows nothing about quoted fields - once you set its field separator to `,` it will treat **every** comma as a separator, and hence consider your string to be two fields. You will need to use one of the more CSV-aware solutions proposed in the answers to [your earlier question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341133/selecting-rows-in-a-csv-file-based-on-column-value-that-contains-an-embedded-com)

Answer (score 1):

In line with my answer to [your earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341133/selecting-rows-in-a-csv-file-based-on-column-value-that-contains-an-embedded-com), using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), and assuming the CSV is properly quoted and uses commas as delimiters:

```
$ csvgrep -c "cancel reason" \
    -m "Wanted item later, choose not to get it later" input.csv >input1.csv
```

or

```
$ csvgrep -c 4 -m "Wanted item later, choose not to get it later" input.csv >input1.csv
```

Comment: When I run your first command this is error I get: usage: csvgrep [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
               [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z FIELD_SIZE_LIMIT] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H]
               [-v] [-l] [--zero] [-n] [-c COLUMNS] [-m PATTERN] [-r REGEX]
               [-f MATCHFILE] [-i]
               [FILE]
csvgrep: error: unrecognized arguments: Wanted item later, choose not to get it later unsubscribe1_22.csv

Comment: When I run your second command and type cat input1.csv this is what I get: cancellation date,customer first name,customer email,cancel reason,cancel reason comments

Comment: @CharlesMarshall You may have to update your installation of `cvskit`.  I'm using version 1.0.1. However, all the argument used by the commands that I suggested are listed as valid by the error message.

Comment: I made sure the latest version csvkit was installed and when I ran the above two commands, I received the same exact output as before. @Kusalananda

Comment: @CharlesMarshall Did you forget the `-m` or did you not quote the string after it?

Comment: No I did not.  It is the same exact command.  I could send it to you to see if it runs on your side?  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting to have 5 fields. This will identify lines with more fields:

```
awk -F, 'NF > 5' input > output
```

This does not specifically look for a comma in the fourth field.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E ',"[^"]*,[^"]*"|"[^"]*,[^"]*",' input.csv > input1.csv
```